# WordPress: help simplify if elseif list loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, if-statement

I'm new to WordPress themes and was hoping you can help me simplify this loop. The biggest thing is to eliminate the need to have the list item twice, though I welcome other suggestions for improvement as well.

I appreciate all the help and will mark the correct answer. Thank you.

```
<ul>

<?php if (is_page('about')) { ;?>

    <?php
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=6"); 
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

        <li>blah blah blah</li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Some error message or similar.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php } elseif (is_page('history')) { ;?>

    <?php
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=4"); 
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

        <li>blah blah blah</li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Some error message or similar.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php } ?>

</ul>
```

---

Thank you rayman86. This did require a few tweaks to get working:

```
<?php 
if (is_page('about')) { 
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=6"); 
} elseif (is_page('history')) {
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=4"); 
}

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

        <li>blah blah blah</li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Some error message or similar.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>

<?php 
if (is_page('about')) { 
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=6"); 
} elseif (is_page('history')) {
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=4"); 
}

if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>

        <li>blah blah blah</li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Some error message or similar.</p>


</ul>
```